# How sockaddr holds sockaddr_storage or sockaddr_in6?

Tags: c, sockets, posix

I am reading Beej's guide, and he talks about the different structers programmers created.
He says we can pass sockaddr_storage/in6/in to addrinfo, and it will be converted to sockaddr,
but how exactly is it possible? sockaddr is 16 bytes, while sockaddr_in6 is 28 bytes.

I read a little part of RFC 3493:

> Notice that the sockaddr_in6 structure will normally be larger than
>   the generic sockaddr structure.  On many existing implementations the 
>   sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) equals sizeof(struct sockaddr), with both
>   being 16 bytes.  Any existing code that makes this assumption needs
>   to be examined carefully when converting to IPv6.

But it doesn't explain what happens when sockaddr_in6 is casted to sockaddr.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember that all functions that take a `struct sockaddr` pointer, also takes the *size* of the structure. Together with the meta-data on the actual socket, it's easy for the system to know what kind of structure you're passing.

Also note that it's always *pointers* to the address structures being passed around, not actual structures which would not work. So you never to e.g.

```
(struct sockaddr) a_in6_sockaddr
```

you do

```
(struct sockaddr *) &a_in6_sockaddr
```

Comment: so sockaddr is pretty meaningless, I mean, it won't change a thing if the function took void pointer instead?

Comment: @BBLN Not really. The functions take a `sockaddr` pointer just because they have always done so ever since they were created.